# Handling one-to-many relationship using ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, one-to-many

I'm struggling to use one-to-many relationship in my small android project. I have distilled the problem (I'm learning java). My program crashes when tries to add the a child object to a parent. I have spent some time to solve it. I need little support to be back on track. Thanks.

```
public class Master {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Parent big;
        big = new Parent("aParent");
        big.addChild(new Child("c1"));
        big.addChild(new Child("c2"));
        for (Child ch : big.getChildren()) {
            System.out.println(ch.toString());
        }
    }
}

public class Parent {
    public String name;
    public List<Child> children = new ArrayList<Child>();
    public Parent(String name) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.name = name;
        this.children = null;
    }
    public void addChild(Child c) {
        this.children.add(c);
    }
    public List<Child> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }
}

public class Child {
    public String name;
    public Child(String s) {
        this.name = s;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: Java throws very explanatory exceptions when "crashing". You should include the stack trace of these when posting questions.

Comment: You are right. I will do it next time. Anyway the response was amazingly quick. I'm impressed. BTW, I spent some time making my code "clean", without android stuff - I think it is good practice.

Answer (score 3):

I bet your crash is a `NullPointerException`.

This happens because, in your `Parent` class:

- You initialize the `children` `List` as an instance statement
- However, you re-assign the `children` `List` reference to `null` in your constructor (which is called **after** and programmatically) - see your code: `this.children = null; // to remove`

Therefore, once the `addChild` method is called, you are trying to `add` the parameter to a `null` `List`

Comment: Yes, it is NullPointerException. I will check. Fine. It is working. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

`this.children = null;` is your problem, delete it, and give a try

It causes NullPointerException in your add method

Answer (score 1):

Remove this line: `this.children = null;`

You are wiping out the ArrayList you created here:

```
public List<Child> children = new ArrayList<Child>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a field initializer and a constructor initialization. Comment out this line:
this.children = null;